# Python Threading with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

Im building a Crawler/Spider and using threading.

**Step 1.** 
The first step im doing is getting all links from website

**Step 2.**
The second step is getting meta data from the requested url and then saving it to mysql database.

Im a bit in doubt, when i get all the links, i go true all of them and find meta data, and at the same time i save the data to mysql.

Note: Foreach thread i create a new DB connection, **is that bad?**

As i can see mysql is using 100% cpu.

**Step 3. ?**
Whould it be better to get the result of meta and then after threading is done, save it to DB?

Is it bad practice to use threading to save to DB, and if so **would it be better to save the data after im finish getting the requested data?**

Any good idea's?

Comment: Accessing a DB from different threads is pretty normal for many applications, but you should be aware what the [threadsafety](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety) of the used connector is. If it's 1 then using one connection per thread, like you do, is what you should do. Other then that, without seeing your actual code it's hard to say more.

Comment: Hi @mata whould it be better to use multiprocessing instead of threading for the inserts in mysql?

Comment: Probably not, but that depends on the acutal program. It would only help if cpu usage by your program is the bottleneck, not the DB or network IO.